# How to make a smaller table from a larger one (Oracle)

Tags: oracle

Say you're using a database called LotOFData that contains a lot of data. I want to take some aspects from this large database and make it its own mini database called LessData and then use that database for my next queries. But I don't know how to do this.

So my LessData would be all the data i got from this query

```
    select *  from LotOFData where shapes = shape1 or shapes = shape2
```

And this would be the new query I'd like to make using that LessData table

```
    select * from(
    (select part from LessData where shapes = shape1) 
    natural join (select part from LessData where shapes = shape2) )
```

Comment: Does the question pertain to database or tables?

Comment: I voted to close based on the question describing a _database_, which is much too broad of a question.  If you are just asking about getting as subset of a single _table_ in your database, please edit your question.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the query you want to be able to run; a natural join won't return any rows - `shapes` is a common column so it will join using that, and no rows can have `shapes` equal to both 'shape1' and 'shape2'? Anyway, are you sure you actually want a new permanent table, which will go stale? Are you really trying to simplify your queries - so perhaps really need a CTE, or (if you need this often) a view, or even a materialized view; or possibly a temporary table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LotOFData and LessData are called tables in SQL. In Oracle you could create your smaller table with a create table as select statement like this:

```
create table LessData as select * from LotOFData 
where shapes = 'shape1' or shapes = 'shape2';
```

I put quotes around the shapes assuming the shapes column was a string.

To query LessData you would just use this:

```
select * from LessData;
```

That select would get the data for both shape1 and shape2.

Bobby